# byte[] to string to byte array conversion did not work fine in java

Tags: c#, java, byte

I have a byte array initialised like this:

```
public static byte[] tmpIV =  {0x43, (byte)0x6d, 0x22, (byte)0x9a, 0x22,
                         (byte)0xf8, (byte)0xcf, (byte)0xfe, 0x15, 0x21,
                         (byte)0x0b, 0x38, 0x01, (byte)0xa7, (byte)0xfc, 0x0e};
```

If I print it it gives me

```
67   109    34      -102       34     -8          -49      -2      21      33
11    56    1       -89       -4      14
```

Then I converted the whole byte array into string and sent to my friend.

```
String str = new String(tmpIV);
```

My friend is a C# programmer

So my friend gets some other data. How my friend will get the same data as I have sent.
Also In Java if I reconvert the above string into byte array I am not getting the exact one that I have sent:

```
 67     109        34        -17        -65      -67      34       -17     -65       -67
-17     -65        -67        -17         -65    -67      21       33    11     56      1
-17      -65      -67         -17       -65       -67
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you've converted the byte array into a string in the platform default encoding.

If this is arbitrary binary data (which it appears to be) then you shouldn't use *any* normal character encoding to convert it into a string - use base64 instead.

Using base64 from Java isn't *particularly* easy (because it's not in the standard libraries AFAIK) but there are various 3rd party libraries you can use, such as [the one in the Apache Commons Codec library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).

On the C# side it'll be a lot easier - just use:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure both you and your friend use same encoding protocol. Therefore, in terms of Java, instead of `String aString = new String(byteArray)` it is better to use `String aString = new String(byteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` (for example if both of you prefer "UTF-8")

PS: By the way, probably you found that the byte array from your friend has following pattern "-17 -65 -67" several times. In my experience, these three number pattern means "?" character in UTF-8

Answer (score -4):

I agree with previous answer - you should use base64 approach but using base64 is easy ;). Just use base64 util classes from *sun.misc* package:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Base64Test {

    public static byte[] tmpIV = {0x43, (byte) 0x6d, 0x22, (byte) 0x9a, 0x22,
            (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0xfe, 0x15, 0x21,
            (byte) 0x0b, 0x38, 0x01, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0xfc, 0x0e};


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String encoded = new BASE64Encoder().encode(tmpIV);
            System.out.println(encoded);
            byte[] decoded = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encoded);
            System.out.println(Arrays.equals(tmpIV,decoded));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use classes from non-standard APIs!!